# Numpy threadpool size in main process changes when fork occurs

Tags: python, numpy, fork

On importing Numpy, the underlying BLAS library used by Numpy allocates a threadpool. This is expected, and can be observed by simply running:

```sh
cat /proc/<my python pid>/status | grep Threads
```

What is weird is that if my main process ever calls `fork()`, all these threads vanish in my main process. To be clear, this is the **main** process (I know forked processes don't retain copies of parent threads).

This behavior is easily reproduced. Exact thread numbers may vary by machine:

```py
import numpy as np  # main process has 36 threads
import os

os.fork() # main process has 1 thread
```

I would like to understand this behavior and where it is coming from, but I'm having a hard time tracking it down.

I'm using Python `3.6.9` and Numpy `1.18.4`.

Answer (score 2):

After some digging, the reason for the behavior is explained here:
https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/issues/294

Also worth noting that threads are spawned once again if I try to do a computation after the `fork()` that requires Numpy to use underlying BLAS library.